Change the alignment in Visual Studio Code find window
I was working in VS Code, and accidentally hit a key combination. Now the alignment in the window in Visual Studio Code has switched to right-to-left. How should I switch it back?
Note that this is find in file (not global find) window. Also note that this is specifically for Visual Studio Code and not Visual Studio.


did you change a language setting?
